# Only ALTER a TRIGGER if is exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am implementing an auditing system on my database. It uses triggers on each table to log changes.
I need to make modifications to these triggers and so am producing ALTER scripts for each one.
What I'd like to do is only have these triggers be altered if they exist, ideally like so:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'TR' AND name = 'MyTable_Audit_Update')
BEGIN
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_Audit_Update] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
 AFTER Update
...
END
```

However when I do this I get an error saying "Invalid syntax near keyword TRIGGER"

The reason that these triggers may not exist is that auditing can be enabled/disabled on tables which the end user can specify. This involves either creating or dropping the triggers. I am unable to make the changes to the triggers upon creation as they are dynamically created and so I must still provide a way altering the triggers should they exist.

Comment: Try adding `GO` between your `BEGIN` and `ALTER` lines.

Comment: Thanks, but that gives an error saying it can't find the trigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alter statement has to be the first in the batch. So for sql server it would be:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'TR' AND name = 'MyTable_Audit_Update')
BEGIN
EXEC('ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_Audit_Update] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
 AFTER Update
...')
END
```

Comment: Just as a side note, I would write the trigger out first, test it and then wrap it with the EXEC as trying to debug within an EXEC() can be difficult

Answer (score 2):

This might be a similar issue to [one that I found with Sybase years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307942/1030), where I found that when trying to execute a `create table` statement conditionally, the DDL is executed prior to assessing the conditional statement. The only workaround was to use `execute immediate`.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), I failed to find a reference that explicitly states that

> CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement in the batch

but it seems that this restriction applies to `ALTER TABLE` too.

The simple way to do this would be to DROP the TRIGGER and re-create it:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'TR' AND name = 'MyTable_Audit_Update')
     DROP TRIGGER MyTable_Audit_Update 
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_Audit_Update] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
AFTER Update

...
END
```